# Split JSONArray into smaller JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have come across a situation where the org.json.JSONArray object is of a huge size, which is eventually causing delay and other problems. Because of this we decided to split the JSONArray in smaller chunks. 
For example, if JSONArray is something like this:

```
- [{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"child1ss","status":"1","dob":"2014-10-02 00:00:00.0","last_name":"childSs"},
{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"suga","status":"1","dob":"2014-11-05 00:00:00.0","last_name":"test"},
{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"test4a","status":"1","dob":"2000-11-05 00:00:00.0","last_name":"test4s"},
{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo56","status":"0","dob":"2000-11-04 00:00:00.0","last_name":"Demo5"},{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"testsss","status":"1","dob":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.0","last_name":"testssssssssss"},{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"Demo1234","status":"0","dob":"2014-11-21 00:00:00.0","last_name":"Demo1"},{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo2433","status":"1","dob":"2014-11-13 00:00:00.0","last_name":"demo222"},{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo333","status":"0","dob":"2014-11-12 00:00:00.0","last_name":"demo344"},{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"Student","status":"1","dob":"2001-12-03 00:00:00.0","last_name":"StudentTest"}]
```

than I need help to divide the JSONArray in three JSONArrays:

```
- [{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"child1ss","status":"1","dob":"2014-10-02 00:00:00.0","last_name":"childSs"}, {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"suga","status":"1","dob":"2014-11-05 00:00:00.0","last_name":"test"}, {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"test4a","status":"1","dob":"2000-11-05 00:00:00.0","last_name":"test4s"}]


 - [{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo56","status":"0","dob":"2000-11-04 00:00:00.0","last_name":"Demo5"}, {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"testsss","status":"1","dob":"1900-01-01 00:00:00.0","last_name":"testssssssssss"}, {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"Demo1234","status":"0","dob":"2014-11-21 00:00:00.0","last_name":"Demo1"}] 


 - [{"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo2433","status":"1","dob":"2014-11-13 00:00:00.0","last_name":"demo222"}, {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"demo333","status":"0","dob":"2014-11-12 00:00:00.0","last_name":"demo344"}, {"alt_party_id_type":"xyz","first_name":"Student","status":"1","dob":"2001-12-03 00:00:00.0","last_name":"StudentTest"}]
```

Can somebody help me in this. I tried many option but failed to do so.

Comment: please elaborate over the tried options.

Comment: Are you using any json library? I would recommend gson. (don't parse json yourself, it was already done for you)

Comment: Just get the data into a List and divide it the way you'd like.

Comment: Are you sure org.json is the reason of the slowness, and if so how did you came to this conclusion?

Comment: @HotLicks: Putting data into a List will fail for huge inputs. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/28263474/108326 for details.

Comment: @markusk - Needs to be a pretty huge list for that to be a problem.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, on the order of megabytes. However, JSON files of megabytes or more are not unheard of in integration scenarios.

Comment: @markusk - My lowly box can handle 800mb of heap.  Even with the expansion that comes with List/Map that would be 5mb of JSON or so.  Much beyond that, in one chunk, is abusing the JSON mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When processing huge input files, you should use a streaming approach instead of loading the whole document into memory, to reduce memory footprint, avoid `OutOfMemoryError`, and make it possible to start processing whie reading input. JSONArray has little support for streaming, so I would recommend looking into [Jackson's streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi), [GSON streaming](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming), or similar.

That being said, if you insist on using JSONArray, you can cobble together a streaming method by using JSONTokener. Here's a sample program that will stream an input file and create separate JSON documents with at most 10 elements each.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.*;

public class JsonSplit {

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;

    public static void flushFile(List<Object> objects, int d) throws Exception {
        try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("split-" + d
            + ".json");
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(objects);
            jsonArray.write(writer);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int outputIndex = 0;
        try (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(args[0]))) {
            JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(input);
            if (tokener.nextClean() != '[') {
                throw tokener.syntaxError("Expected start of JSON array");
            }
            List<Object> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<>();
            while (tokener.nextClean() != ']') {
                // Back up one character, it's part of the next value.
                tokener.back();
                // Read the next value in the array.
                jsonObjects.add(tokener.nextValue());
                // Flush if max objects per file has been reached.
                if (jsonObjects.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
                    flushFile(jsonObjects, outputIndex);
                    jsonObjects.clear();
                    outputIndex++;
                }
                // Read and discard commas between array elements.
                if (tokener.nextClean() != ',') {
                    tokener.back();
                }
            }
            if (!jsonObjects.isEmpty()) {
                flushFile(jsonObjects, outputIndex);
            }
            // Verify that end of input is reached.
            if (tokener.nextClean() != 0) {
                throw tokener.syntaxError("Expected end of document");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

To see why a streaming approach is needed for huge files, download or create a huge JSON file, then try running a naive implementation that doesn't stream. Here's a Perl command to create a JSON array with 1,000,000 elements and a file size of around 16 MB.

```
perl -le 'print "["; for (1..1_000_000) {print "," unless $_ == 1; print "{\"id\": " . int(rand(1_000_000)) . "}";} print "]"' > input_huge.json
```

If you run `JsonSplit` on this input, it will churn away happily with a small memory footprint, producing 100,000 files with 10 elements in each. Also, it will begin producing output files immediately when started.

If, instead, you run the following `JsonSplitNaive` program, which reads the entire JSON document in one go, it will apparently do nothing for a long period, then abort with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.json.*;

public class JsonSplitNaive {

    /*
     * Naive version - do not use, will fail with OutOfMemoryError for
     * huge inputs.
     */

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;

    public static void flushFile(List<Object> objects, int d) throws Exception {
        try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("split-" + d
            + ".json");
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(objects);
            jsonArray.write(writer);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int outputIndex = 0;
        try (InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(args[0]))) {
            List<Object> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(input));
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                jsonObjects.add(jsonArray.get(i));
                // Flush if max objects per file has been reached.
                if (jsonObjects.size() == BATCH_SIZE) {
                    flushFile(jsonObjects, outputIndex);
                    jsonObjects.clear();
                    outputIndex++;
                }
            }
            if (!jsonObjects.isEmpty()) {
                flushFile(jsonObjects, outputIndex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Down voted this, as the answer is simply a statement without any arguments to reason why a different library should be used. My experience with org.json is good.

Comment: @Paul: I've added some justification for my statements, and also added a sample program for streaming a large JSON array and split it into multiple files. Does this address your concerns?